# Morphisms of smooth varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective morphism of varieties (integral separated schemes of finite type over an algebraically closed field) such that $Y$ is smooth projective and all the fibers are connected smooth projective. Is $X$ necessarily a smooth variety? If $f$ were flat, smoothness of $X$ would be automatic but we consider non-flat morphisms as well.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  That is not true.  Let $Y$ be $\mathbb{P}^2_k = \text{Proj}\ k[s,t,u]$.  Let $Z$ be $\mathbb{P}^1_k = \text{Proj}\ k[x,y]$.  Inside the product scheme $Y\times_{\text{Spec}\ k} Z$, let $X$ be the zero scheme of the following bihomogeneous polynomial of bidegree $(2,1)$: $p = s^2x+t^2y$.  Let $f$ be the restriction to $X$ of the projection to $Y$.  This is probably the simplest example of a projective Abelian cone that is irreducible yet not smooth.  To learn more about this, confer Section 2 of the following:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305432.pdf

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  It appears that there may be some issues with your use of this site.  If you have similar questions, please feel free to e-mail me directly.